# How to disable linting in vim (no, it's not ALE)

Tags: vim, linter

Recently, the vim built into my Mac has started to show me linting feedback visually whenever I save.  This is annoying and I'd rather it not happen.  (Previous 20 years of using vi/vim did not have this behavior.)

My web searching suggests perhaps it's ALE, so I tried to disable it with `:ALEToggle`, but vim replied with "E492: Not an editor command: ALEToggle."  So I don't think it's ALE.

The gutter shows many instances of `S>` as the indicator of where linting feedback resides, and then highlights characters within those lines as points of concern.  See examples in screenshot below.

**What linter uses `S>` and how do I disable it globally, for all files?  I don't need or want this feature.**

[image: Screenshot of linting feedback in a Python file]

The relevant parts of my `~/.exrc` file are here.  (Note that things like `^H` had to be typed out, because trying to paste them here failed for obvious reasons.)  There is a little more than this in my file, but everything not shown here I've tried commenting out and it doesn't help, so it's not the problem.

```
execute pathogen#infect()
set ai
set ts=4
syntax on
set expandtab
set nu
filetype indent off
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set hlsearch
set ignorecase
set t_Co=256
colorscheme wombat256mod
map ^H :nohlsearch<Enter>
set mouse=a
set relativenumber
```

Comment: can you please include your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @JoshBode Done, thank you.

Comment: Thank you :) Also, can you please add the output of `set rtp?` to show what plugins are possibly being loaded on the runtime-path? And does the issue persist if you comment out the line `execute pathogen#infect()`? `:help local-additions` may also shine some light on any plugins being loaded.

Comment: @JoshBode Progress!  First, `set rtp` gave `runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/julia-vim,~/.vim/bundle/nim.vim,~/.vim/bundle/sy
ntastic,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,
~/.vim/after`.  Second, commenting out pathogen makes the problem go away.  Third, running `:help local-additions` I don't think I understand the output fully, but I think it's saying my only local addition is `syntastic-checkers.txt`.

Comment: By the way, I definitely recommend using something like [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a more modern plugin manager over Pathogen - it's much more explicit about exactly what plugins are being loaded, and provides an update function to keep plugins fresh :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're getting style warnings from [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/plugin/syntastic.vim).

Either you can remove the plugin by deleting `~/.vim/bundle/syntastic` or you could try adding this to your Vim config:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = {"mode": "passive"}
```

Comment: Very close!  This helped put me on the path to the right answer, which is actually to use `g:syntastic_mode_map = {'mode':'passive'}` instead.  But I want you to get credit, so please update the answer and I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it fixed :) Otherwise, these things are just an endless distraction ;)